# Как сделать плавное движение?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтоб не рывком ширина div увеличилась а плавно?

```
<style>
 #menu { background: #000; width: 200px;    height: 30px;}
</style>

<div id="menu"  onclick="active()"></div>

<script>
function active(){  
    var x = document.getElementById('menu').style.width;
    if (x == '400px'){  x = '200px';}
    else{x = '400px';}      
    document.getElementById('menu').style.width = x;
}   
</script>
```

Comment: лучше конечно на javascript

Comment: почему лучше на яваскрипте, а не, например, css?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function animate(elem, style, unit, from, to, time) {
    if (!elem) return;
    var start = new Date().getTime(),
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            var step = Math.min(1, (new Date().getTime() - start) / time);
            elem.style[style] = (from + step * (to - from)) + unit;
            if (step == 1) clearInterval(timer);
        }, 1);
    elem.style[style] = from + unit;
}

var w1 = 200,
    w2 = 400;
menu.addEventListener('click', function () {
    animate(this, 'width', 'px', w1, w2, 1000);
    w1 = [w2, w2 = w1][0];
}, false);
```

```css
#menu {
    background: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu"></div>
```

Comment: а easing кто писать будет? : )

Answer (score 0):

В active() присвой блоку #menu класс yourclass. В ксс #menu добавь параметр transition (например 200ms). Потом добавь селектор #menu.yourclass, в котором поставь другое значение width, например 400px

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с помощью CSS3 анимации. Добавить св-во `transition`, в котором обозначить, что св-во `width` должно меняться в течение 2 секунд. И по клику менять ширину, добавляя класс с другим значением `width`:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('menu');

function toggle(){
    var classes = el.className.split(/\s+/),
        i = classes.indexOf('active');
    if ( i == -1) classes.push('active');
    else classes.splice(i,1); 
    el.className = classes.join(' ');
}
el.addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

```css
#menu{background:#333; width: 200px; height: 30px; transition: width 2s;cursor:pointer;text-align:center;color:#FFF;line-height:30px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica;}
.active{width: 400px !important}
```

```html
<div id="menu">нажми меня</div>
```

[Фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/1qm6ytm4/)

---

**Upd.** [без класса](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/1qm6ytm4/1/) выглядит лаконичнее, но придётся каждому элементу давать ширину явно.